# Automatically sign all commits with git

Tags: git, pgp

With git 1.7.9, it's possible to sign a commit with the `-S` option. Is it possible to set it default through `git config --global`?

So instead of `git commit -S -m 'Commit message'`, it would be just `git commit -m 'Commit message'`.

Comment: It is possible with new git with `commit.gpgsign=true` setting.

Comment: @Vi, could you post your comment as an answer, please? Your fit better now days

Comment: @davidmpaz, Answers cannot be added to a closed question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To sign automatically all future git commits, you can define a global alias. For example, to create a global alias called "c", you would do this:

```
$ git config --global alias.c 'commit -s'
```

(note that the commit switch to sign off is lowercase "-s" and NOT uppercase "-S", as you typed in your question).

After having done this, you can start doing your commits using your newly created "c" alias. Here's an example of creating and commiting a file called "test.txt" that will be signed off by the committer:

```
$ vim test.txt
[edit file]
$ git add test.txt
$ git c -m 'My commit message'
```

You can see that the commit has the "Signed-off-by:" line if you run the "git log" command with the `--pretty=fuller` option:

```
$ git log --pretty=fuller
```

Comment: `-s` adds a "signed off by" field to the commit.  `-S` actually PGP signs the commit, which was added in git 1.7.9.  Also, this does not sign all commits, but only those which are made by the user directly using the `git c` command.  In a rebase, when new commits are created, this will not sign off on (or PGP sign) the commits, unless you do an interactive rebase and manually commit every change.

Comment: For more information on signing commits, see here: https://phreaknerd.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/signing-git-commits-with-your-gpg-key/ for instance